# Which Android emulator to use with Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

Bear with me, I'm a gardener not a programmer!

Been playing with Xamarin on Visual Studio and I can't get an emulator to work. It's VS 2017 community, Windows 10 Pro (version 1803), Processor is an Intel Quad Core Q9550, 8gb Ram and it's 64-bit.

The emulator image that came with the default install was Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo(Android 8.1 - API 27). It'll launch but just hangs on a black screen. Same effect with the other images I've added through AVD Manager on Android Studio (version 3.3.1). Do any of them work on my set up? I'd like that 30gb of memory back if not!

I believe the PC can't manage Second Level Address Translation (SLAT) which rules out Hyper-V.

There's a visualisation hardware setting in the BIOS and it's turned on.

According to the installer I need Windows 8.1 Pro to get the VS Emulator to work so I can't have that either.

Installed Bluestacks, poked about with "adb connect localhost:5555" on the command line and a Google Pixel XL emulator appeared in VS. Assume that's Bluestack? Launch Bluestack first and then start the default Xamarin template in VS. Should display a "Welcome to Xamarin Forms" label in XAML as I believe but just drops out with "java.exe exited with code 1".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See below snaps It will help you to create an efficient emulator

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Android Studio.

Go to Tools -> AVD Manager -> +Create Virtual Device.

Comment: Hello Ryan, made a handful of new ones already.

Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
VCPU shutdown request
emulator: WARNING: Not saving state: emulator hasn't finished booting.

New question, how to format a reply?! Sorry!